# #include <atlrx.h> error

Tags: atl

I have a Visual Studio project that fails on compile with this error : "cannot open include file 'atlrx.h' : No such file" .

I was told that I should download ATL server from Codeplex and install the files.
I have downloaded ATL Server, but i don't know how to proceed.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

OOps,

I just needed to copy the include file to a folder on my hard disk  and set Visual Studio (Tools|Options|VC++ Directories) to point to the copied folder.